# Firebase index required but no link provided

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> Tip: instead of creating indexes here, run queries in your code – if you're missing any indexes, you'll see errors with links to create them.
> [Learn more](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#error-links)

I'm getting an error `no matching index found` without the usual direct link to create the index required.

[image]

My database is structured as follows:

```
answers (collection)
  - $docId (document)
      - $refId (collection)
          - $docId (document)
              - created_at (timestamp)
              - type (string)
```

My query is:

```
firebase.firestore()
 
 .collection('answers')
 .doc('abcdHajM930Gabcd')
 .collection('abcdetIo25xYqAabcd')
 .orderBy("created_at", "desc")
 .limit(5)
 .where("type", "==", "3")
```

I've tried all combinations of indexes I could think of (screenshot below), What am I doing wrong?

| collection | field | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| answers | created_at: DESC | type: ARRAY |
| answers | created_at: DESC | type: ARRAY |
| answers | created_at: DESC | type: ASC |
| answers | created_at: DESC | type: ASC |
| answers | type: ASC | created_at: DESC |
| answers | type: ASC | created_at: DESC |

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** The [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152) seems to be fixed and Javascript client SDK now returns the index creation link.

---

I'm not totally sure if that's intended by the Firebase JS SDK or no, but if you try running your query in a Cloud Function (just use the emulator) then it should throw an error containing the link to create the index.

```
export const getIndexLink = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    //   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
    try {
        const snap = await admin.firestore().collection('answers')
            .doc('abcdHajM930Gabcd')
            .collection('abcdetIo25xYqAabcd')
            .where("type", "==", "3")
            .orderBy("created_at", "desc")
            .limit(5).get()
        console.log(snap.size)
        response.send("Hello from Firebase!" + snap.size);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        response.send(error.message)
    }
});
```

I tried copying your query and created an index using the URL and the index turns out to be:

[image]

Your fields that your are using are not a part of documents of "answers" collection. Now if you change the sub-collection name, it'll require another index. What does your Firestore structure look like? I'd recommend restructuring it a bit and get a same sub-collection name and create an index with collectionGroup scope.

Comment: Update: There's a [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152) for the same.