# Android Studio does not show link to create firestore index

Tags: android, firebase

I use firestore for my one of my android applications, whenever I run my app and if there are firestore queries get triggered in it which require index to be created in firestore Android Studio / firestore sdk used to show that URL in logcat console. This seems to have stopped after recent updates of either Android Studio or firestore dependencies.

I have enebaled firestore loggin in my app, when I open the app where firestore query is triggered, I see the following in logcat but no link to create the index automatically

```
I/Firestore: (22.0.1) [WatchStream]: (25c2d74) Stream received: # com.google.firestore.v1.ListenResponse@e6b130b4
    target_change {
      cause {
        code: 9
        message: "no matching index found."
      }
      target_change_type: REMOVE
      target_change_type_value: 2
      target_ids: 172
    }
```

I also see firestore logging my query in logcat

```
I/Firestore: (23.0.2) [WatchStream]: (2d5d4c2) Stream sending: # com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest@14c8c909
    add_target {
      query {
        parent: "projects/helpline-bly/databases/(default)/documents"
        structured_query {
          from {
            collection_id: "sample"
          }
          order_by {
            direction: ASCENDING
            direction_value: 1
            field {
              field_path: "state"
            }
          }
          order_by {
            direction: DESCENDING
            direction_value: 2
            field {
              field_path: "modified"
            }
          }
          order_by {
            direction: DESCENDING
            direction_value: 2
            field {
              field_path: "__name__"
            }
          }
          where {
            composite_filter {
              filters {
                field_filter {
                  field {
                    field_path: "createdby"
                  }
                  op: EQUAL
                  op_value: 5
                  value {
                    integer_value: 0
                    string_value: "UGdydNYpAbRpDIH8qcNX"
                  }
                }
              }
              filters {
                field_filter {
                  field {
                    field_path: "state"
                  }
                  op: NOT_EQUAL
                  op_value: 6
                  value {
                    integer_value: 0
                    string_value: "COMPLETE"
                  }
                }
              }
              op: AND
              op_value: 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
      target_id: 172
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far

1. Invalidate Caches/ Restart (multiple times)
2. Used older firestore dependencies
3. Reinstalled Android Studio (new version as well older version)

update:

I wrapped my firestore query with try-catch block, I see firestore throws an error but still no link there

```
#lambda$observeQuery$0$BaseFragment: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found.
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:117)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(EventManager.java:166)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.removeAndCleanupTarget(SyncEngine.java:588)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(SyncEngine.java:424)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider$RemoteStoreCallback.handleRejectedListen(MemoryComponentProvider.java:99)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(RemoteStore.java:577)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:461)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(RemoteStore.java:53)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:176)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:108)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:38)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1$AbstractStream$StreamObserver(AbstractStream.java:119)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$AbstractStream$StreamObserver$IZBnAkL3D_hQ5ofbDpSmX2lhuPo.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(AbstractStream.java:67)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(AbstractStream.java:110)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(FirestoreChannel.java:125)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:658)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:643)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:229)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found.
        at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:541)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:115)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(EventManager.java:166) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.removeAndCleanupTarget(SyncEngine.java:588) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(SyncEngine.java:424) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider$RemoteStoreCallback.handleRejectedListen(MemoryComponentProvider.java:99) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(RemoteStore.java:577) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:461) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(RemoteStore.java:53) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:176) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:108) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:38) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1$AbstractStream$StreamObserver(AbstractStream.java:119) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.-$$Lambda$AbstractStream$StreamObserver$IZBnAkL3D_hQ5ofbDpSmX2lhuPo.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(AbstractStream.java:67) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(AbstractStream.java:110) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(FirestoreChannel.java:125) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:658) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:643) 
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) 
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:229) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2021-07-15 16:08:42.416 27162-27280/com.atomnest.helpline D/StreamDownloadTask: Initial opening of Stream failed
    java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.createDownloadStream(StreamDownloadTask.java:145)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.access$000(StreamDownloadTask.java:36)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(StreamDownloadTask.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(StreamDownloadTask.java:164)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.ensureStream(StreamDownloadTask.java:325)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.access$100(StreamDownloadTask.java:262)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(StreamDownloadTask.java:175)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7$StorageTask(StorageTask.java:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.-$$Lambda$StorageTask$q9YBoR_A8LB-JxTCx8JRQvabaZs.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

earlier the error used to be something like this

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/exam-package/database/firestore/indexes?...
```

Any help on this would be very helpful

Comment: There are lots of similar issues. Try using Cloud functions emulator as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388195/firebase-index-required-but-no-link-provided/68388387#68388387) or you can manually create an index.

Comment: I tried creating an index manually but there are many things to take like order of the fields, ascending or descending etc. For few complex queries it is becoming very tedious to create it

Comment: Can you share your query? I may be able to create one.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but there are many queries that need to be created in my project. Is there a way we can get the link like we used to get it before?

Also, if I have to use Cloud functions, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388195/, I will have upgrade my project

Comment: You don't need to be blaze plan to use the local emulator.

Comment: I will check how to setup that and run, will post an update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234906/discussion-between-abdulh-and-dharmaraj).