# "Error getting documents: FirebaseError: no matching index found." -- trying to use WHERE clause on two fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a where clause on two fields. I was surprised to find I couldn't use inequality clauses on two different fields, but I've changed my clause to use "in", and tried this:

```
await db.collection("Colours").where("beta", "in", [3, 4, 5, 6]).where("alpha, "!=", [])
  .get()
...
```

and no longer get the inequality error, but do get this:

```
Error getting documents:  FirebaseError: no matching index found.
```

Is there any way around this? I'm really disappointed that I can't seem to be able to use two where clauses! The alternative is to filter on the client side, but that would require reading everything from the first clause, right? My data has lots of documents, and it will result in a lot of Firestore reads, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

There is a GitHub issue on this.  See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an index in Firestore for that. In your Firebase console, head to Firestore and switch to <kbd>Indexes</kbd> tab. Then create a new **composite** index as shown below:

[image]

Make sure your collection name and field names are correct and in proper case.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to have solved my issue, it's finished building and status is "Enabled", but I still get the Error.

Comment: @Joseph can you please share a screenshot of the index created and a sample document? I'll try running the same query by copying your document.

Comment: sure, here's a document: https://imgur.com/a/3aQ6Jhg; and here's the index: https://imgur.com/a/8kmGu1Y

Comment: @Joseph I just ran the query as in your original question and it worked for me. https://imgur.com/a0T7Tsx What query did you try? The original or something else?

Comment: hmm, that's strange! My full query is this: ```await db.collection("Colours").where("beta", "in", [3, 4, 5, 6]).where("alpha", "!=", [])
        .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                  var result = doc.data();
                  console.log("+++++++++++++");
                  console.log(result);
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
          });```

Comment: @Joseph what error are you getting? Is it the same or something new?

Comment: Yep, the same: ``Error getting documents:  FirebaseError: no matching index found.``

Comment: @Joseph I ran the same query again with that index and it's working. I'd say try restarting all emulators or your functions again.

Comment: I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong then in that case :/ I don't have any emulators or functions; I deployed to firebase again; restarted my localhost and it gives the error on the firebase hosted and my localhost

Comment: @Joseph can you please try setting up a new Firebase project locally with functions, add your query in the functions file, emulate the functions locally and it should throw an error that the index is missing but should contain a link along with it. Try creating an index using that link as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68388387/13130697) and let me know if that works ?