# Firebase does not provide link to create indexes and manual index does not work

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was used to getting a link from the console to inform me there was a need to create an index when searching for documents in a firebase collection. Now it seems I am not getting any more the index. The console is providing this error

> [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because
> the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution.
> If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase
> console.

Here is my query:

```
_firestore
          .collection('photos')
          .where('seen', isEqualTo: '')
          .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: appData.user.uid)
          .where('interest', isEqualTo: appData.userInterest)
          .limit(1)
          .get()
          .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {

        if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {//
```

I believe the issue may be that I am using the operator "isNotEqualTo" but maybe it is an issue with Android studio.

I have tried to make the index manually but failed to create an index that works.
[image]
I use Android Studio and flutter.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase index required but no link provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388195/firebase-index-required-but-no-link-provided). This answer was for Javascript SDK but this issue is same for all SDKs. You can use the workaround in that answer.

Comment: Hello, the GitHub link (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152) seems to be relevant. However in my case it seems it does not work even if I create the index...

Comment: Yes it's the issue. In some cases manually create index doesn't seem to be working. If you wish to create an index using the link then you may have to use Admin SDK as explained in the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the Admin SDK as explained int he answer"?

Comment: Checkout the answer whose link is in my first comment above ^

Comment: I can't see any answer than to add manually the firebase console. this seems not to work for me

Comment: Have you seen this [comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152#issuecomment-880438961) in that Github issue?

Comment: Oh I understand now what you mean. Well I do not have cloud function in this project. It seems an overkill to create a function just for that...

Comment: True, it's just a work around and you don't even have to deploy it. Just emulate is locally.

Comment: Until there is a [repro] this question is not reproducible and is unlikely to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

This was a server problem at Firebase.

See here the [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152) to the resolution.

The issue has now gone and I get link to create the indexes when needed.